# Highlighting cells with different colors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this example code to highlight specific cells of a table.
Please have a look at the fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/hzss885e/

Here I can select multiples of different values and highlight them to green color at the same time. What I would like to do is when I click a "select all" button, I'd like the selected values (4 different values) to be highlighted in 4 different colors. The color choice is not important. May be there is a simple solution to this for a javascript expert, but I can't figure it out with my limited knowledge of jquery. I appreciate all responses. thanks.

```
$('.selector').each(function() {
$(this).on('click', check); 
});
$('.all').each(function() {
   $(this).on('click', all); 
});

function all(event) {

    if($(this).is(':checked')){       $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)",$(this).parents('form')).not(this).prop("checked","checked");
} else {
    $("input:checkbox(:checked)",$(this).parents('form')).not(this).prop("checked","");
}

//$('.selector').prop("checked", this.name === "SelectAll");

check(event);
}

function check(event) {
var checked = $(".selector:checked").map(function () {
    return this.name
}).get()
$('td').removeClass("highlight").filter(function () {
    return $.inArray($(this).text(), checked) >= 0
}).addClass("highlight")
if ($(this).is(".selector"))
    $('.all').not(this).prop("checked", false)

}
```

Comment: can you give cells with content a class or id specific to its content, or can you not modify the table?

Comment: The table is an example code. There will be more data and on that case it would be difficult to implement it. @depperm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to your `check` function:

```
// remove all previously set background colors
$('td').css({background: ""});

// create an object we will store our randomly generated colors on
var colors = {};

$(".highlight").each(function () {
    colors[$(this).text()] = colors[$(this).text()] || getRandomColor();
    $(this).css({background: colors[$(this).text()]});
});
```

With `getRandomColor` being:

```
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

See the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gtkmb10o/5/).

Comment: I noticed it just now. The code you provided highlight all the same values with different colors. For example, if there are three "x" values in the selection, they will be all highlighted in different colors instead of one color. @cdMinix

Comment: Thank you. it is my mistake, I didn't notice it at first glance.

Comment: @Max Also [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtkmb10o/6/) if you want the colors to stay the same.